# flutter how to use future async method in init state

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, future

When the screen loads i want the init state to fill the List with Future<List> that is passed through the stateful widget. However since its a future, my method will crash and not work.

My code

```
  @override
  void initState() async {
    FutureBuilder(
      future: widget.imageList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            print('NONE');
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            print("WAITING");
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            print("DONE");
            setState(() {
              imgList = widget.imageList as List<String>;
            });
            break;
        }
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }
```

Error Produced

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
_BottomSheetWidgetState.initState() returned a Future.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp
```

Stateful widget where the list is passed through

```
List<String> imgList = List<String>();

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomSheetWidget({Key key, this.name, this.imageList}) : super(key: key);

  String name;
  Future<List<String>> imageList;
```

Whole edited code:

```
List<String> imgList = List<String>();

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomSheetWidget({Key key, this.name, this.imageList}) : super(key: key);

  String name;
  Future<List<String>> imageList;

  @override
  _BottomSheetWidgetState createState() => _BottomSheetWidgetState();
}

class _BottomSheetWidgetState extends State<BottomSheetWidget> {
  int _current = 0;

  final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
      .map((item) => Container(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.network(item,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 1000.0, width: 1000.0),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0.0,
                        left: 0.0,
                        right: 0.0,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [
                                Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                                Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                              ],
                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              end: Alignment.topCenter,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ))
      .toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: widget.imageList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
            print('NONE');
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            print("WAITING");
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            print("DONNE");
            setState(() async {
                imgList = snapshot.data as List<String>;

            });

            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CarouselSlider(
                          items: imageSliders,
                          options: CarouselOptions(
                              enlargeCenterPage: true,
                              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 500,
                              aspectRatio: 2.0,
                              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _current = index;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: imgList.map((url) {
                            int index = imgList.indexOf(url);
                            return Container(
                              width: 8.0,
                              height: 8.0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: _current == index
                                    ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                                    : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                              ),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                        Text(widget.name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        Text("United Kingdom",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
            break;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

New error from console:

```
flutter: WAITING

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
A build function returned null.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<List<String>> 
lib/common_widget/bottom_sheet.dart:54
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: DONNE

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
setState() callback argument returned a Future.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<List<String>> 
lib/common_widget/bottom_sheet.dart:54
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: this should be done inside build method, not in initt

Comment: I am still learning flutter and classed as a beginner. The only reason i put it inside init state was because i want that to run first before anything else. So if i were to include it inside the build would it still run first?

Comment: The `FutureBuilder` widget provides you with a [snapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/builder.html) which contains details of whether the future has completed amongst others. You could use this to check if the future has completed before rendering other widgets that depend on the result of the future. Any widgets returned from within the `builder` callback function of the `FutureBuilder` will be created after the `FutureBuilder` has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `initState` method is synchronous by design. Rather than creating the `FutureBuilder` widget in the `initState` method, you could return the `FutureBuilder` widget in the overridden `build` method. Feel free to take a look at the documentation for the `FutureBuilder` widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#widgets.FutureBuilder.1) for an example of how this could work.

It looks like there is also an issue with the code in the `setState` callback function. You probably want to replace `imgList = widget.imageList as List<String>;` with `imgList = snapshot.data as List<String>;` in order to use the data from the completed future.

It looks like there is also an issue with the `build` method not returning a widget in all the cases. I have taken your updated code sample and modified it as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomSheetWidget({Key key, this.name, this.imageList}) : super(key: key);

  final String name;

  final Future<List<String>> imageList;

  @override
  _BottomSheetWidgetState createState() => _BottomSheetWidgetState();
}

class _BottomSheetWidgetState extends State<BottomSheetWidget> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: widget.imageList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final imgList = snapshot.data;

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            ),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CarouselSlider(
                        items: imgList.map(
                          (item) {
                            return Container(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.network(
                                        item,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        height: 1000.0,
                                        width: 1000.0,
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        bottom: 0.0,
                                        left: 0.0,
                                        right: 0.0,
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                              colors: [
                                                Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                                                Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                              ],
                                              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                              end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ).toList(),
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 500,
                          aspectRatio: 2.0,
                          onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                            setState(() {
                              _current = index;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: imgList.map((url) {
                          return Container(
                            width: 8.0,
                            height: 8.0,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: _current == imgList.indexOf(url)
                                  ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                                  : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "United Kingdom",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using that i have managed to get it somewhat working before i can accept your answer i am getting this error within the done case.     type 'Future<List<String>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast. I believe this happens in the set state

Comment: Would you be able to post an updated code sample of the `BottomSheetWidget` and the `_BottomSheetWidgetState`?

Comment: Perfect, I have updated my answer based on the updated code sample.

Comment: Hmmm, having tried that i still get an error, i updated my code above

Comment: Apologies, I missed another issue which is your `build` method not returning a widget in all the cases.