# How can I receive data in Dart with onGenerateRoute bevor the build function runs?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart I want to send data from '/city' to '/card' with the onGenerateRoute.

```
class RoutGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute (RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home());
      case '/city':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => City());
      case '/card':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Cardd());
    }
  }
}
```

The data I want to send is from a JSON with a list of maps (for example: {(oid: 1, webcode: TSGBF, name: Berlin), (oid: 2, webcode: HSJAT, name: London), ...}.
I build a card for each map and onTap I want to send the oid and the webcode to '/card' :

```
String oid;
  String webcode;
  CityState({this.oid, this.webcode});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Städte"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
               oid = (data[index]["oid"]);
               webcode = (data[index]["webcode"]);

              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/loadcard', arguments: {
                'oid': oid, 'webcode': webcode
              });

            },
...
```

And here comes the problem. The oid and the webcode are part of the URL I need for the '/card'-page. How can I get the two Strings from the first page and implement them into the URL so the right page will load before the build function runs?

```
class Cardd extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  CarddState createState() => CarddState();
}

class CarddState extends State<Cardd> {

  List info;

  Future<void> getInfo() async {
    var antwort = await http.get('http://www. ... webcode=$webcode&ort_id=$oid ...');
    this.setState(() {
      info = jsonDecode(antwort.body);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getInfo();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( 
...
```

*Edit

I imported the package "shared_preferences" and saved my data in a local storage with this code:

```
void saveData(oid, webcode) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('oid', oid);
    prefs.setString('webcode', webcode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Städte"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: //(data != null) ?
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              saveData(data[index]["oid"], data[index]["webcode"]);

              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/toilet');
            },
...
```

After that I can receive it on the other page with:

```
  String oid;
  String webcode;


  Future<void> loadData() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    oid = prefs.getString('oid');
    webcode = prefs.getString('webcode');
  }


  List info;

  Future<void> getInfo() async {

      await this.loadData();

      var antwort = await http.get(
          'http://www. ... $webcode&ort_id=$oid ... ');
      this.setState(() {
        info = jsonDecode(antwort.body);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need something in Future before widget is built. Maybe you are looking for the `FutureBuilder`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Also you need to add some other widget when data is not ready yet (loading page).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution and solved the problem with a local storage. I implemented the shared_preferences dependency for this.

Comment: That's great. I am still curios how you achieve it using shared_preferences. Isn't shared_preferences also a Future function need to wait for?

Comment: I called the getData function with await in front of the http.get function. I also edited my code so you can see the exact code.

Comment: From the original code, I see a problem that it is not safe to use ` Future<void> getInfo()` inside `void initState()` because the initState is Synchronize function and won't wait the Future function done. You can try to add some delay into `getInfo()` pretend the data need to get for a long time. I think `oid` & `webcode` will still remains null when you use it in build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639479/flutter-how-to-use-future-async-method-in-init-state

Comment: I added a delay and as you said it didn't work anymore. Thank you for your advice I will try to get myself into the FutureBuilder and hopefully I can get a solution today.