# Waiting for Async Data in InitState

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to get data from a Future to a Stateful widget before it displays on startup. I have tried async/await, FutureBuilder, and the Sync package implementing a WaitGroup within the initState method; however, nothing I do waits for the data to return from the Future before it renders the screen.

In the below examples, I have a simple String strName that I initialize to "Default Name" that I am using for testing and displaying in the Scaffold. It only displays the initialized "Default Name," and not the name returned from the Future. The closest I got was using a FutureBuilder, at least it updated the screen after the initialized "Default Name" was shown. However, I need to get the data prior to the screen rendering. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's an example of what I tried with Sync WaitGroup:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String strName = "Default Name";

  Future<String> _getName() async {
    var name = await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => "New Name");
    return name;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WaitGroup wg = WaitGroup();
    wg.add(1);
    Future<String> futureName = _getName();
    futureName.then(
      (value) {
        strName = value;
        wg.done();
      },
    );
    wg.wait();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(strName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              strName,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what my async/await method looked like:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String strName = "Default Name";

  Future<String> _getName() async {
    var name = await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => "Jimbo");
    return name;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Future<String> futureName = _getName();
    futureName.then(
      (value) {
        strName = value;
      },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(strName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              strName,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've never worked with a language where there asynchronous is the default structure of so many parts. How do you deal with making async synchronous in Dart? I haven't even got into the SQLite and HTTP part of it, and it is killing me. I've been at it for four days and got so frustrated I almost broke a keyboard yesterday.

Comment: This has been already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639479/flutter-how-to-use-future-async-method-in-init-state

Comment: You might fetch data before coming into this screen. BTW it will just take some fraction of time to load in this in screen,

Answer (score 0):

**The best is to use a loading screen while fetching your data**
and use `snapshot.data`

full implementation using FutureBuilder:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String strName = "Default Name";

  Future<String> _getName() async {
    var name = await Future<String>.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 5), () => "New Name");
    return name;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(strName),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: _getName(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    snapshot.data!,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is really a bad practice**
but if you really need to resolve some future data before the app renders you can use the `void main()` method.

```
void main()async {
  Future<String> futureName = _getName();
    futureName.then(
      (value) {
        strName = value;
        runApp(MyApp());
      },
    );
  
}
```